# Парсер выдает не все значения

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Пишу парсер, он должен перебрать 5 стр. по 50 знач. и на выходе 250 знач., но фактически выдает 200, т.е. перебирает 4 стр. В чем проблема?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = []

for p in range(1, 6):
  url = f"https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/?page={p}"
  page = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
  films = soup.findAll('div', class_='styles_root__ti07r')



  for film in films:
    meta_inf = film.find('span', class_='desktop-list-main-info_secondaryText__M_aus').text.replace("\xa0мин.", "")
    meta_inf2 = film.find('span', class_= 'desktop-list-main-info_truncatedText__IMQRP').text.replace("\xa0.", "")
    link = "https://www.kinopoisk.ru" + film.find('a', class_='base-movie-main-info_link__YwtP1').get('href')
    rus_name = film.find('span', class_='styles_mainTitle__IFQyZ styles_activeMovieTittle__kJdJj').text
    year = re.findall(r'\d+', meta_inf)[0]
    duration = re.findall(r'\d+', meta_inf)[1]
    country = meta_inf2.partition(' •')[0]
    director = meta_inf2.partition('Режиссёр: ')[2]
    genre = meta_inf2.partition(' • ')[2].partition('Режиссёр:')[0][:-2]
    roles = soup.findAll('span', class_='desktop-list-main-info_truncatedText__IMQRP')[1].text.partition('В ролях: ')[2]
    raiting = soup.find('span', class_='styles_kinopoiskValuePositive__vOb2E styles_kinopoiskValue__9qXjg').text

    data.append([rus_name, link, year, duration, director, country, genre, roles, raiting])
len(data)
```

200

Comment: я бы повыводил кол-во ссылок. которое найдено на каждой с 5 страниц. Возможно, это подскажет  направление поиска. Также можно спросить поддержку кинопоиска

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что у меня получилось

```
<Response [200]> https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/?page=1
<Response [200]> https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/?page=2
<Response [200]> https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/?page=3
<Response [200]> https://www.kinopoisk.ru/showcaptcha?cc=1&retpath=https%3A//www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250%3Fpage%3D4_6b0aaf665bed002528936197ae3b5408&t=2/1653573994/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&u=cb13d61f-f70af52f-3a34a320-ab124f50&s=4ee319e71f2556c5685453195f87aaa9
<Response [200]> https://www.kinopoisk.ru/showcaptcha?cc=1&retpath=https%3A//www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250%3Fpage%3D5_a7c234fddafe29f24f0b8b6b270221c2&t=2/1653573994/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&u=2b5010a-dddfcdd7-75aa59c7-e05a14b6&s=62ffa953a28b0c4625238a2eb3fe3a5b
```

последние два запроса капча, видимо поняли, что вы бот

как проверить?

```
for p in range(1, 6):
  url = f"https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/movies/top250/?page={p}"
  page = requests.get(url)
  print(page, page.url)
```

Comment: круто, я думал, что этот сайт не работает давно. У меня даже через прокси не открывается.

Comment: Спасибо!!! А как вы это проверили? Я новичок, только изучаю python...

Comment: Я тоже новичок :) ответ обновил. Насколько мне известно у кинопоиска есть API.